# Django cant get registration form to post to database in admin.py

Tags: django, python-3.6

Hi I am trying to get my ModelForm to post to my database so I can see if users are actually registered in my database the view for the registration is called (Registernow). The actual database shows up in admin.py but when I enter the information in my Django made ModelForm it will not POST to the database therefore I will not see any registered users under my ModelForm in admin.py, could you please help me?

```
VIEWS.PY

from django.shortcuts import render
from App1 import forms
from App1.forms import LogInForm, SignedUpForm
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login, logout
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.template import RequestContext



# Create your views here.
def index(request):
    form = LogInForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        emailview = request.POST.get('email')
        passwordview = request.POST.get('password')
        varauth = authenticate(username=emailview, password=passwordview)
        if varauth:
            if varauth.is_active:
                login(request, varauth)
                request.varauth
                return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Account Not Active")
        else:
            print("Someone tried to log in and failed")
            print('Username: {}\nPassword: {} '.format(emailview, passwordview))
    return render(request, 'App1/index.html', {'form': form})

@login_required
def special(request):
    return HttpResponse("YOU ARE LOGGED IN")

@login_required
def activeuserlogout(request):
    logout(request)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))

def terms_and_conditions(request):
    return render(request, 'App1/termsandconditions.html')

# LAST EDITED CHANGE IN THE POST GET PARAMETER
def Registernow(request):
    form2 = SignedUpForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = SignedUpForm(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
            instance = form2.save(commit=False)
        else:
            form2 = SignedUpForm()
            HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('index'))
    return render(request, 'App1/register_now.html', {'form2' : form2})

def main_face(request):
    return render(request, 'App1/mainface.html')

END VIEWS.PY
*********************************************************************

FORMS.PY

from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from App1.models import LogInModel, SignedUpModel

# LOG IN MODELFORM
class LogInForm(ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs=
    {'placeholder': 'example@gmail.com'}))
    password = forms.CharField(label='', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=
    {'placeholder': 'password'}))
    class Meta:
        model = LogInModel
        fields = {'email', 'password',}
        class Media:
            css = {
                '__all__': 'style_sheet_signin.css'
            }
# END MODELFORM
class SignedUpForm(ModelForm):
    name = forms.CharField(label='Name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
    {'placeholder' : 'First Name'}))
    lastname = forms.CharField(label='Last Name', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
    {'placeholder' : 'Last Name'}))
    email2 = forms.EmailField(label='Email', widget=forms.EmailInput(attrs=
    {'placeholder' : 'example34@gmail.com'}))
    password2 = forms.CharField(label='Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=
    {'placeholder' : 'Password'}))
    passconf = forms.CharField(label='Confirm Password', widget=forms.PasswordInput(attrs=
    {'placeholder' : 'Confirm'}))
    phone_num = forms.IntegerField(label='Phone Number', widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=
    {'placeholder' : 'eg. 5196329087'}))
    class Meta:
        model = SignedUpModel
        fields = {'name', 'lastname',
         'email2', 'password2', 'passconf', 'phone_num',}
    class Media:
        css = {
            '__all__': ('registrationbonky.css')
        }
# END MODELFORM

END FORMS.PY
******************************************************************

MODELS.PY

from django.db import models
# LOGIN MODEL AND MODELFORM HERE
class LogInModel(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField()
    password = models.CharField(max_length=256)

# END MODEL
# SIGNIN IN MODEL

class SignedUpModel(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    email2 = models.EmailField()
    password2 = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    passconf = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    phone_num = models.CharField(max_length=20)
# END MODEL

END MODELS.PY
*******************************************************************
HTML REGISTRATION PAGE FORM

  <form class="" action="{% url 'App1:index' %}" method="POST">
      <h3 id='rege'>REGISTRATION</h3>
      <br>
      {% csrf_token %}
      {{form2.as_table}}
      <br>
     <input id='regebtn' type="submit" name="" value="REGISTER">
    </form>

***************************************************************
***************************************************************
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I see you haven't committed the [save on your model form instance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#the-save-method).

If you'd want to add customized data to your instance, that makes sense, but you haven't used your instance later and you haven't saved it. So it won't be persisted in the database when RegisterForm gets posted to the server.

Something like this would do:

```
def Registernow(request):
    form2 = SignedUpForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form2 = SignedUpForm(request.POST)
        if form2.is_valid():
        instance = form2.save(commit=True)
        ...
```

Comment: Oh, I never knew you had to do that in your forms or models I only did it for the view lol. Thanks for writting in &#128522;